# Разрешить Android app запросы на http

Tags: java, android, http, post, https

заканчиваю некий проект под платформу Android где смартфон на Android является клиентом и шлет запросы на сервер,получает ответы распарсивает и т.д., в общем классика). Возникли проблемы, так как дебажил и тестил на своем смартфоне(Android 7.0)-их не было выявлено-все было отлично и готовился продакшн, но когда привезли целую партию боевых смартфонов, которые будут использоваться в бизнес проекте, оказалось что они капризные китайщины на 4.4.2, выявился страшный недочет. Все запросы можно делать только на заверенные сертификатом ssl сайты(домены), при попытке запроса на http приложение вылетает. Как можно подружить китайца с HTTP обычным?

Comment: Какой http клиент используете? OkHttp? Apache?

Comment: Родной sdk HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

Comment: Stack trace в вопрос добавьте.

Comment: С ним ведь были проблемы и его уже исключили из SDK, зачем Вы его используете? Ну может проблема и не в этом, покажите лог ошибки, что ли. И как насчёт стокового браузера - он тоже не открывает "не безопасные" сайты?